# Getting 'round , strange behavior of my shell while using adb to connect to a mobile

Tags: android, shell, terminal, adb, developer-tools

I made aliases on my `Linux` to establish `wireless adb` connections & `mirroring` .
these are listed as `a1 & a2` in the code below.

**Situation**
-After running `a1  & a2` ( esp. if there was a pre-existing connection that disconnected ) it initially fails. Repeating these again ( ~ X 5 times ) will successfully connect.
-if I run the individual commands referred within a1 and a2, serially & separately  - It will connect at the 1st shot.
-if I run all commands referred to in `a1 & a2` together or do `a1`  && `a2` it will give me a "Vendor keys not recognized" error .

**Questions**
-How do I go about  getting this done via aliases like a1 & a2 
-Why does it initially not want to  & repeated attempts successfully connect. 
-why do I get `"Vendor keys not recognized" error`

```
root# alias a1
alias a1='adb kill-server && sleep 2 && adb tcpip 5555  && adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555'
root# alias a2
alias a2='adb -s 192.168.43.1:5555 shell'
```

Repeated attempts

```
root# a1
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
unable to connect to 192.168.43.1:5555: Connection refused
root# a1
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
connected to 192.168.43.1:5555



root# a2
error: device '192.168.43.1:5555' not found
root# a1
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
unable to connect to 192.168.43.1:5555: Connection refused
root# a1
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
connected to 192.168.43.1:5555
root# a2 
/# <-- connection successful
```

running alias contents together with `'anded' aka &&` conditions . No connection established.

```
root# adb kill-server && sleep 2 && adb tcpip 5555  && adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
connected to 192.168.43.1:5555
root# adb -s 192.168.43.1:5555 shell
error: device '192.168.43.1:5555' not found
root# adb kill-server && sleep 2 && adb tcpip 5555  && adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
connected to 192.168.43.1:5555
root# adb -s 192.168.43.1:5555 shell
error: device '192.168.43.1:5555' not found
root# adb kill-server
root# adb tcpip 5555
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

running everything together - `vendor keys error` and before that it was the regular

```
root# adb kill-server && sleep 2 && adb tcpip 5555  && adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555   &&  adb -s 192.168.43.1:5555 shell
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
connected to 192.168.43.1:5555
error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

running everything together serially and separately. connects in 1 shot.

```
root# adb kill-server
root# adb tcpip 5555
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
root# adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555
connected to 192.168.43.1:5555
root# adb -s 192.168.43.1:5555 shell

/#  <-- connection successful
```

adding to that the fact the adb server is running  ( after *a1* is run  )  but does not like a `connect` command via `alias`

```
root# pss adb
+ grep -i adb
+ ps -ef
root      1642  9454  0 05:13 pts/1    00:00:00 grep -i adb
root     27630     1  0 05:04 ?        00:00:00 adb -L tcp:5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 4
root# adb devices
+ adb devices
List of devices attached
39b2a4210606    device
```

running the check function....

```
+ grep 192.168.43.1
+ grep -q device
+ adb devices
+ printf .
.+ sleep 1
^C
root# adb devices
+ adb devices
List of devices attached
39b2a4210606    device

root# a2
+ adb -s 192.168.43.1:5555 shell
error: device '192.168.43.1:5555' not found
```

wont help cos it ain't some related to timing . Matter o'f  I did  try a loop ( directly without function ) sometime  ago  & it will run forever. Its related to `adb server` being available. If I run these command directly - `ps o/p` will be same as above.

 the timing issue is ruled out 'cos invariably running serially without alias will run fine .Also if I run an inline shell

```
  <<EOF
<code> EOF ;
```

same issue. Something needs to 'emulated in batch' so as to say a functionality of running command & 'getting to the prompt' again before running the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Probaby a timing issue if running the commands manually succeeds.

Then, add some check for the device to be ready

```
w1() { while :; do adb devices | grep "$1" | grep -q device && break; printf '.'; sleep 1; done; printf '\n'; }
```

and you can run

```
$ a1 && w1 192.168.43.1 && a2
```

#### update

If `39b2a4210606` is the device you want to use

```
$ a1 && w1 39b2a4210606 && a2
```

may work too.

Comment: updated my answer. It keeps  `looping` . Doesnt seem like timing...the prob is running vide that alias does not somehow make `adb` available 'openly' ...ct in the Q update above